# "Have to" in progressive tenses

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

So, are they possible if I use "have to" in progressive tenses?

For examples:

> A. She is having to take care of her.
>
> B. She was having to have a bath.
>
> C. She will be having to walk to her school.
>
> D. You can make a call without having to wait for a long time.
>
> E. You can remove car dents without having to repaint.

Comment: D and E are not progressive tenses. They are gerunds after a preposition.

Comment: But are D&E correct as gerunds?

Comment: A-C don't really makes sense - just replace "having" with "has" and it works out a lot better (in C, "be having" with "have" instead)

Comment: So, how about this one, I've found it from BBC,For example: She said: ''My colleagues and I are having to deal with hundreds of cases where things have gone wrong because the wedding has not been registered

Answer (score 1):

1. All examples are grammatically correct.
2. Examples A, B and C use "have to" in progressive tenses.
3. Examples D and E do not use "have to" in progressive tenses.
4. The use of progressive tenses with "have to" in not usual. Just use simple tenses.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @virolino's answer:

"Have" followed by to-infinitive forms the auxiliary with the meaning similar to "must".

Try as I might, I couldn't find any source warning against using "have to (do something)" in the progressive.

At the same time, in contexts of the immediacy of doing something *right now*, it seems quite appropriate, if not usual, to use it in the –ing form to put emphasis on the moment of speaking or the relevant period of time rather than expressing the general idea of the necessity/obligation.

[For examples of the usage see here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+having+to%2Cwas+having+to%2Cwere+having+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20having%20to%3B%2Cc0).